# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() on this "==" operator Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, operator-keyword

I have a script like this

```
if vms2['STATUS'] == 1:
    vms2['entry']=vms['STATUS']+vms2['status_after']
else :
    vms2['entry']=vms['STATUS']+vms2['status_before']
```

it shows error like this:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am new in Python, so I can'f figured the source of the error. Please help.

EDIT:
sample dataframe:

| STATUS | status_before | status_after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

Comment: Please add code to initialize a small sample dataframe for this question. We should be able to run the code and get your error.

Comment: already added. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

For conditional logic of whole Series or array, consider `numpy.where` and not `if...else` that expects scalar comparison. Remember pandas/numpy programming noticeably differs from general purpose Python programming.

Below uses the functional form of arithmetic `+` operator (i.e., `Series.eq`, `Series.add`):

```py
vms2['entry'] = np.where(
    vms2['STATUS'].eq(1),
    vms2['STATUS'].add(vms2['status_after']),
    vms2['STATUS'].add(vms2['status_before'])
)
```

Comment: thanks! When I use np.where, can it used with 2 level of np.where? it is like using multiple IF.

Comment: Yes, you can nest `numpy.where` and if mutually exclusive conditions, consider `numpy.select`. Many StackOverflow pandas questions on this method.

Answer (score 0):

`vms2['STATUS'] == 1` is a series of True/False values.

```
>>> vms2 = pd.DataFrame({"STATUS":[1,1,3,]})
>>> vms2["STATUS"] == 1
0     True
1     True
2    False
```

is `vms2['STATUS'] == 1` true if there is at least one `1` in the column? Perhaps all of the values need to be `1`? That depends on the requirements of this bit of code, its not something pandas can guess in general. Instead, use one of the methods mentioned in the error code. Since `==` returned a `Series` you can put it in parens for grouping and then chain the method.

```
>>> if (vms2["STATUS"] == 1).any():
...     print("foo")
... 
foo
```

Comment: What I want is basically compared values from several columns for each rows. I added the sample dataframe in the question.

Comment: @Parfait has a good answer to that (got my vote). Consider giving an initialized dataframe in code like the exmaple above. The goal is something that we can copy / change and repost as a tested solution.